# tomcat with https sends separate packet

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

When using tomcat7 with https,i found that the content of the packet should be in the one packet,but it is transmitted to two packets.
I think the setting of ssl is ok.I can access web with htpps,or use `wget --ca-certificate=/home/alice/root.crt https://IP:8443`, it shows 200 ok.

Here is logs of conversation with tomcat.

```
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[336](func_send): release qbuf to empty_qbuf_head ok.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[279](func_send): wait SEM_SEND.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[702](sock_recv): result=1 Recv Data _pdb: H
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[432](func_recv): res=1 Recv Data p_data: H
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[435](func_recv): colin bbb TO func_recv countqn=1
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[436](func_recv): insert qbuf to recv_qbuf_head ok.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[493](func_recv): post SEM_RECV.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[402](func_recv): colin aaa TO func_recv countqn=2
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[410](func_recv): get qbuf from empty_qbuf_head ok.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[418](func_recv): colin ready to sock_recv.
    Thu Sep  2 10:17:24 2015,comm.c[702](sock_recv): result=1285 Recv Data _pdb: TTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    SOAPAction:
    Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
    Content-Length: 1124
    Date: 02 Sep 2015 02:16:51 GMT
```

The "Recv Data _pdb" is the packet whick i receive.I receive `H` and then `TPP/1.1 ...`,it makes something error. If receive `HTTP/1.1 ...`, everything is fine.
Generally,the packet should be `HTTP/1.1 ...`,but it shows that tomcat sends packet `H` and packet `TTP/1.1 ...`.

I found some setting of HTTP connector `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html`,but nothing relates this problem.

Tomcat version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
OS : 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

This is part content of server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/home/jack/example.pkcs12"  
           keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

Any one has idea? Let me know which side is wrong. Thanks.

2015/09/03 update : 
At server side,i use tcpdump to catch packet, and open wireshark to resolve it.Because device receives H and TPP/1.1,so the session is not completely;therefor,we can't use wireshark with private key to decrypt packet.I only can see data length to guess it. As previous shown, tomcat sends two packets.

Comment: Is this specific to tomcat or does it happen with the other https sites too? It might the way wget is reading the data not how tomcat is sending them.

Comment: Using browser to access web site is ok. I install freeacs (http://www.freeacs.com/) and has device which supports tr069 propocol.The conversation of tomcat and device shown in the above.
Tr069 protocol is using Http/1.1,so don't confuse by it.
(reference : https://www.broadband-forum.org/technical/download/TR-069_Amendment-4.pdf , p37)

Comment: The question was not if you can access this site with a browser, but if the tool you use shows the same behavior with other https sites or if it shows this behavior only for your tomcat site. In the first case it might not be caused by tomcat, but by the tool you use works with https connections.

Comment: Some things may cause confusion. This tool supports tr069 and ssl protocol,and tr069 communication site is fixed, so there is no way to use this tool to test other site. I know what you want to express, so I need to find another server that supports tr069 and ssl,and then use the same way to test.

Answer (score 0):

They are both right. The HTTP protocol is not defined in *packets*, but as a stream of bytes. The underlying TCP/IP protocol must chomp the stream into packets, but they are reassembled in order on the receiving end.

If your code reads HTTP, then it must wait for more input. It cannot assume that data arrives together or in certain chunks.

The end-of-data is well-defined in HTTP. The HTTP header ends when 2 pairs of  `CR LF` is received (`CR LF CR LF`). If the header indicates a payload, then the header must either:

- Specify the size in bytes (`Content-Length`)
- Use [chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`)
- Not use `keep-alive`. The data ends when connection is closed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It still has something confusing me.When i use http and ssl (https), it's randomly to appear this situation. But when i use http,everything is ok(receive "HTTP/1.1..."). It just add ssl handshake step,but effect of the packet.

Comment: @Phantom That's correct. It's apparently random. It isn't under your control. It isn't under Tomat's control. It isn't under HTTPS's control. It isn't under SSL's control. Segmentation is determined entirley by TCP, and packetization is determined entirely by IP. And undone at the other end. If your application is sensitive to TCP segmentation or IP packetization it is written incorrectly. TCP is a byte-stream. Period. It can deliver as little as one byte at a time.

Comment: Thanks,EJP. It sounds that i need to increate something(i.e.,buffer size) which to avoid segmentation. If it is not under tomcat's control, should i find setting at os(ubuntu) ?

Comment: @Phantom You're missing the point. If you haven't received enough data yet, wait for more data to arrive. *You* have to collect the data until you have enough for your need. The more incremental *your* processing is, the less *you* have to buffer. Example: You're processing the response status line, which ends with a `CR LF`, so you'll likely want to buffer until the first `CR LF`, then you have your status line, potentially guarding against malicious attacks trying to cause buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I will try to use your comment. It's need some time to implement. Thanking you again for your reply.